# How to change the LabelStyle only for one axis?

Tags: plotting

I want to modify the style of just one axis, but I'm stuck with something like

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, LabelStyle -> Red]
```

which of course modifies both axes. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Look up `AxesStyle` and `TickStyle`

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this must be a duplicate but depending on what features you want to alter (just label, label and ticks etc) you might have to use combinations of `AxesStyle` and `TickStyle` and so on but here is a quick example:

```
Plot[x x, {x, 0, 3}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Black, Directive[Black, FontColor -> Red]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just as a small addition to the answer of Mike Honeyhurch, if you need to not only change the color, but also some other ticks properties, try this:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, 
 TicksStyle -> {Black, Directive[Red, FontSize -> 14, Italic]}]
```

[image]